# T-SQL: Add another column with some commands

Tags: t-sql

i have a script below to find all the db fixed role db_datawriter. this is working fine, no issues. what i want to do is come up with a series of commands:

drop the member from the db

So the 5th column will look something like this:

USE dbname ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] DROP MEMBER UserName

This is what i have as the last select statement.

```
SELECT *, 'USE ' + @dbname + ' ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ' + 'DROP MEMBER ' + UserName FROM #UserPermission
```

However, the dbname doesn't change. it keeps listing out the first one. the rest of the string concat works fine.

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50)  

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #UserPermission

(

 DbName SYSNAME,
UserName SYSNAME,
TypeOfLogIn VARCHAR(50),
PermissionLevel VARCHAR(50),
)

 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
LOCAL FAST_FORWARD

FOR 

SELECT name

FROM master.sys.databases

WHERE state_desc='online'

OPEN db_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN 

 

SELECT @statement = 'use '+@dbname +';'+ 'SELECT

 

dbname=db_name(db_id()),p.name as UserName, p.type_desc as TypeOfLogin, pp.name as PermissionLevel

FROM sys.database_role_members roles

JOIN sys.database_principals p ON roles.member_principal_id = p.principal_id

JOIN sys.database_principals pp ON roles.role_principal_id = pp.principal_id

where pp.name=''db_datawriter'' and p.name<>''dbo'''

 

INSERT INTO #UserPermission

EXEC sp_executesql @statement

 

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END 

CLOSE db_cursor 

DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM #UserPermission

DROP TABLE #UserPermission
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply remove the dynamic sql and use this instead?

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50)  

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #UserPermission

(

DbName SYSNAME,
UserName SYSNAME,
TypeOfLogIn VARCHAR(50),
PermissionLevel VARCHAR(50),
)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
LOCAL FAST_FORWARD

FOR 

SELECT name

FROM master.sys.databases

WHERE state_desc='online'

OPEN db_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO #UserPermission SELECT @dbname 

,p.name as UserName, p.type_desc as TypeOfLogin, pp.name as PermissionLevel

FROM sys.database_role_members roles

JOIN sys.database_principals p ON roles.member_principal_id = p.principal_id

JOIN sys.database_principals pp ON roles.role_principal_id = pp.principal_id

where pp.name='db_datawriter' and p.name<>'dbo'

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END 

CLOSE db_cursor 

DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT 'Use ' + QUOTENAME(Dbname) + ' ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(PermissionLevel) + ' '+ ' DROP 
MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(UserName)
from #UserPermission

DROP TABLE #UserPermission
```